# Bug in Stackoverflow styled badge system script

Tags: plugins, php, bug, stackoverflow

I have modified an old Stackoverflow inspired badge system script to work with the latest Wordpress version. You can view the code [here](https://gist.github.com/mistergiri/4005087) (and please feel free to use it if you wish).

It has a condition system that detects `Post tags`, `Post count` and `Comment count`. You can create custom badges and assign conditions to them. It works perfectly besides a very random bug that I cannot fix.

I setup a Wordpress test site and created 10 accounts. I played around with the users and the badges were awarded according to its conditions, so for instance, if a user posted 10 articles, they would be awarded the `Junior Publisher` badge.

However, **one** user was instantly awarded **all** badges when the account was created. This user has no posts or comments. Even more strange, when I add a new badge, this user automatically gets awarded with it! There is no difference between this user and the other users. All have `Contributor` privileges. The user ID number of this user is 5.

**Can you please help me detect why the script is behaving like this?** Obviously, I cannot add the script to a live site yet in scare of random users being awarded all badges like this user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On line 704 it mentions something about "User_ID => 5". Not sure, but this might have something to do with your problem?

```
    // debug stuff
    $args = array('user_ID' => 5);
    rhb_check_user_badges( $args );
```